# Find the address of a specific PivotItem

Tags: excel, vba, loops, pivot, pivot-table

I have the value for `RowField.Name` and the value for `PivotItem.Name` in `RowFields`, I want to highlight the specific cell. But I can't seem to find a way that allows me to loop through every visible RowField.

Ideally I want something like this:

```
Sub LoopThroughPivotAndFindValue()
dim pt as PivotTable, pi as PivotItem, pf as PivotField

Set pt = wb.PivotTables("PivotTableNo1")

For each pf in pt.PivotFields
  For each pi in pf.PivotItems
    If pf.Name = "Test" And pi.Name = "Value" Then
      'Ideally here would be the output of the address within the sheet
    End If
  Next pi
next pf
End Sub
```

Ultimately I want to color specific cells in the pivot table but I cannot seem to find a way to do it properly. There is no index property that I am aware of.

Anyone with an idea?

Comment: If I'm correct in understanding what you're after, you can test for visible PivotItems by evaluating the `.Visible` property. Example: `If pi.Visible = True Then`

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing exactly what your PivotTable looks like, I can't answer exactly, but I can tell you that what you're looking to use is the [GetPivotData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195919.aspx) method where you can name the field and item you're looking to get and it will return a range.

Hope this does the trick!!

Comment: @Spurious : Just click on the link, and you'll have your answer that it work in VBA! ;)

Comment: Sorry for only replying now, but it doesn't seem to work for what I am looking for. I want to get the address of a Row item, I don't seem to be able to get that with the `GetPivotData` method.

Answer (score 1):

An UDF can be useful too, this might be a good start for you :

```
Sub test_Spurious()
    MsgBox LoopThroughPivotAndFindValue("Test", "Value")
End Sub
```

And here is the function :

```
Function LoopThroughPivotAndFindValue(ByVal PivotFieldName As String, ByVal PivotItemName As String) As String
Dim pT As PivotTable, _
    pI As PivotItem, _
    pF As PivotField, _
    FoundIt As Boolean

FoundIt = False
Set pT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

For Each pF In pT.PivotFields
    For Each pI In pF.PivotItems
        If pF.Name = PivotFieldName And pI.Name = PivotItemName Then
            'Ideally here would be the output of the address within the sheet
            On Error GoTo ErrHandler
            FoundIt = True
            LoopThroughPivotAndFindValue = pI.LabelRange.Address
            Exit For
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next pI
Next pF

If FoundIt Then GoTo FreeObjects
ErrHandler:
    LoopThroughPivotAndFindValue = "Nothing"

FreeObjects:
    Set pT = Nothing
End Function
```

So, I'd say the best way is to store the result into a temp variable and check if it is `Nothing` (in plain text, not in a parallel of objects) and then use the address to color it!

Comment: Will try your solution.

Comment: I tried your solution, I have extended it for my purposes as well and changed it a bit, will post my solution as an answer.

Comment: @Spurious : Can you accept answer to validate your question as solved plz?